# chgAction in dropdown menu dosent send email. Worked before

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

So i've created a form that sends an email to me when you click the "skicka"(send on swedish) button. It works 100% and ive tested it, or rather it worked. Since i have a dropdown menu to change email address/form action it dosent work. I tried using javascript chgAction(), I've also tried different methods but this looked easiest. Somethings wrong but i dont know what since i dont receive any emails anymore. Is this a legitimate way of doing this?

Heres my index.php 
NOTE: both kontakt.php and kontakt2.php works since i tried both without beforehand at the form action="".

```html
<?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>HS Konsult</title>
 <meta name="description" content="" /><meta name="keywords" content="" /><!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]--><script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script><script src="js/skel.min.js"></script><script src="js/init.js"></script><noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-xlarge.css" />
  </noscript><!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]--><!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body><!-- Header -->
<section id="header">
<header class="major">
<h1>HS Konsult</h1>

<p>En Hemsida om oss och vilka tj&auml;nster vi erbjuder.</p>
</header>

<div class="container">
<ul class="actions">
 <li><a class="button special scrolly" href="#one">G&aring; Vidare</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
<!-- Two -->

<section class="main special" id="two">
<div class="container"><span class="image fit primary"><img alt="" src="" /></span>

<div class="content">
<header class="major">
<h2>Vad G&ouml;r Vi?</h2>
</header>

<p>Consequat sed ultricies rutrum. Sed adipiscing eu amet interdum lorem blandit vis ac commodo aliquet vulputate.</p>

<ul class="icons-grid">
 <li><!--<span class="icon major fa-camera-retro"></span> -->
 <h3><img alt="Peo" src="/img.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /></h3>
 </li>
 <li><!--<span class="icon major fa-pencil"></span> -->
 <h3><img alt="Camilla" src="/2.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /></h3>
 </li>
 <li>
 <h3><a href="Camilla.html" title="Läs Mer Om Camilla">Camilla</a></h3>
 </li>
 <li>
        <h3><a href="Peo.html" title="Läs Mer Om Peo">Peo</a></h3>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
<a class="goto-next scrolly" href="#three">Next</a></div>
</section>
<!-- Footer -->

<section id="footer">
<div class="container">
<header class="major">
<h2>Kontakta Oss</h2>
</header>

<?php
//tillagd1
//init variables
$cf = array();
$sr = false;
 
if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
    $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
    $sr = true;
}
?>
<ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
    
    <?php 
    if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
        foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
    ?>
    <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>
</ul>
<!--function to run phpfile depending on person selected-->
<script type="application/javascript">
 function chgAction() {
     console.log('chgAction()');
     console.log(form.selectperson.selectedIndex);
     
        if(form.selectperson.selectedIndex=="option1" )
        {document.maillista.action = "/kontakt.php";}
        
        else if(form.selectperson.selectedIndex=="option2")
        {document.maillista.action = "/kontakt2.php";}
 }
    
</script>

<form id="maillista" name="maillista" action="/" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <p>
    <label>Välj Person Att Kontakta</label>
        <Select class="target"id=selectperson name="selectperson" onChange="javascript:chgAction()"> 
            <option value ="option1">Peo</option>
            <option value ="option2">Camilla</option>
        </Select>
    </p>
    
<div class="row uniform">
<div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)"><input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Namn" type="text" /></div>

<div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="john.doe@email.com" type="email" /></div>

<div class="12u$"><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Meddelandet måste vara längre än 20 karaktärer." data-minlength="20" rows="4"></textarea></div>

<div class="12u$">
<ul class="actions">
 <li><input class="special" type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka" id="button1"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
</div>
&lt;

<footer>
<ul class="icons"><!-- <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li> -->
</ul>

<ul class="copyright">
 <li>&copy; HS</li>
 <li>Design:</li>
</ul>
</footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should debug your code to identify either the error location and message, or the point where the code isn't getting hit, then work out the reason why. What do you expect us to do with this wall of code?

Comment: BTW, I expect `selectedIndex` will be a number, not an option value (text)

Comment: @musefan Well thing is i dont get an error. Error log is empty and the page dispalys the thank you message after submit but i dont an email, so i guess it dosent run the php files or it dosent understand which option value is selected? Maybe Im using the function in a wrong way? Im not sure since Im quite new. Is there another option than SelectedIndex?

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.